# startup got selected to exhibit in web summit (zero funding), company doesn't have the fund to cover the expenses

Tags: schengen-visas

This year web summit selected my startup company to exhibit at their summit. They just waived the exhibit ticket for 3 to 1/10 price. We paid the registration and now they are processing our invitation letter. They wont be providing any type of accommodation or travel tickets. We booked our hotel, talking to the travel agency for ticket pricing and managing all the necessary papers.

Since it's a startup and our salary isn't sufficient for the trip neither any of us have the fund in our bank accounts. The company also doesn't have much fund in its account.

So in such case

1. Can our fathers be sponsors to the trip (they have sufficient fund in bank)?
2. Is business visa the right option along with business trip as sub option?
3. Are my pay slips necessary till date (please note sometimes it was paid in cash and sometimes in bank but we have all papers signed that we received the xyz amount that month)
4. Since the company won't be able to sponsor anyone of us, is it necessary to submit company bank account statement?

Comment: My first thought on reading this was 'Is this a scam?'. Are you sure that this 'summit' is really what it says it is? Secondly, you're a start-up company with few resources. Is exhibiting at an event that is clearly going to be expensive to attend really the best use of the resources you have?

Comment: https://websummit.com/

have a look, it's not a scam, this event creates opportunity for startups

Comment: Why the 'french-schengen-visas' tag ? The event seems to take place in Portugal.

Comment: @TanhaIslam: That's exactly what a scammer would claim.

Comment: Web Summit is a large conference in Europe. That said, people have taken particular issue with their fees and marketing to startups in the past (see, for instance [this blog post](http://tech.eu/features/6203/no-web-summit-for-me/)), and it is worth making an honest assessment of whether the opportunities are worth the costs given that the company doesn't have the money.

Comment: @audionuma yes, event is in portugal but in bangladesh French Embassy takes care of Portugal visa that's why.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Gave you link to verify.

Comment: @TanhaIslam Your link verifies that the scammers claim what you say they claim. Have you followed Zach's link?

Answer (score 2):

Except for a few special cases, **sponsorship** for a Schengen visa is no clear-cut legal category.

- They want to know the **reason** for your trip.
- They want to know **your financial circumstances**. Always, even if you cannot afford the trip on your own. Being on a cash basis is usually seen as a bad sign.
- They want to know **who pays and why**. Always, even if you can afford the trip on your own. As I understand it, the **company** pays for the trip and all expenses, so your parents would at best provide emergency funds for you if there are unexpected expenses.

They will always look at income and expenditure, not just the bank balance. That is why they want multiple statements or payslips from you.

You are traveling for business reasons, and saying anything else in the application would be stupid. It would make it look as if you are hiding something.

Comment: I already mentioned that the company itself doesn't have fund to provide me since it's a startup, in that case if my father can be the sponsor for my entire trip.

Comment: @TanhaIslam, so your father donates money to the startup company? Does he get shares for that? Otherwise it would be quite strange.

Comment: no he doesn't have any share neither he donates money to the startup, a start up has very limited money for which it can't bear the cost of the attendee but my father can, I have been to uk for a fest where my entire trip was covered by the fest organizers but still they rejected as my father's account money wasn't sufficient, I applied again with my father's statement, it got accepted

Comment: It is **not just** about the balance, it is about the source of the money and if it appears reasonable to spend it that way. If your father pays for a business trip of the company, then he is giving money to the company. If he doesn't get anything back, that looks **strange**.

Comment: I get your point but earlier for my uk visa (which was covered by a company) my father showed his papers as they asked for it first time.

Comment: It depends on how you frame it, I think. If attending the web summit helps your *personal carrer* clearly more than the startup, it may seen as reasonable that your father sponsors you as he has a clear interest in *you personally* succeeding professionally. It may also be different if you are actually one of the co-founders of the startup. The thing is that your application has to be convincing. The fact that previously a visa officer determined that a similar case was convincing does not help you here, as the visa officer this time may get a different impression about your case.

Comment: @o.m. I presume that "startup" simply means a couple of young software engineers who are working together on a project, not an actual company making money. It would be equivalent to Steve Jobs' parents letting him use their garage to assemble their first Macs, despite not getting any shares of Apple Inc.